# RSolve with assumptions

Tags: bugs, recursion, nonlinear, assumptions, difference-equations

**Bug noticed for Mathematica 8 and persisting through 11.3; Submitted to Wolfram, Inc. as CASE:3729158**

I want to solve the following non-linear first order difference equation:

$$
k_{t+1} = (1-a) k_t^{a}
$$

with $0 < a < 1$, and $k_0 = \text{const.}$ .

Of course, the solution is easily found, but I want *Mathematica* to solve it.

Using

```
RSolve[{ k[t + 1] == (1-a) k[t]^a, k[0] == k0}, k[t], t ]
```

gives

```
{{k[t] -> E^(((-1 + a^t) (I π + Log[-1 + a]))/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t}}
```

The solution is much simpler when considering the restriction on $a$. How can I tell *Mathematica* that $a$ is between $0$ and $1$ when applying the `RSolve` command?

P.S. I've played around with the `Reduce` command, using assumptions, but that did not help.

Comment: Would someone verify that there is a bug with solution returned by `RSolve`?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Bug persists in 11.0.1.  Do you know whether anyone has reported in to Wolfram, Inc.?

Comment: @bbgodfrey No, I don't remember or know.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I have submitted it.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is to take the `Log` of both sides of the recurrence relation, solve the transformed relation, and exponentiate the result.

```
l[t] /. First@RSolve[{l[t + 1] == Log[1 - a] + l[t] a, l[0] == l0}, l[t], t];
FullSimplify[Exp[%] /. l0 -> Log[k0]]

(* (1 - a)^((-1 + a^t)/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t *)
```

By the way, the problem identified by [MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) persists in version 11.0.1.

**Workaround**

A workaround based on a suggestion provided by Wolfram Technical Support for this particular problem is

```
SetOptions[PowerExpand, Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1];
FullSimplify[k[t] /. First@RSolve[{k[t + 1] == (1 - a) k[t]^a, k[0] == k0}, k[t], t],
    0 < a < 1]
SetOptions[PowerExpand, Assumptions -> Automatic]

(* (1 - a)^((-1 + a^t)/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t *)
```

`PowerExpand`, called by `RSolve`, needs to know that `0 < a < 1` to work properly here. Incidentally, `SetOptions[PowerExpand, Assumptions -> True];` also seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the answer appears to be wrong:

```
rsol = First @ RSolve[{k[t + 1] == (1 - a) k[t]^a, k[0] == k0}, k[t], t];
Table[k[t] /. rsol /. {a -> 1/2, k0 -> 1}, {t, 0, 5}] // N // Chop

(* {1., 0.5, -0.353553, 0. - 0.297302 I, 0.192776 - 0.192776 I, 0.241196 - 0.0999066 I} *)
```

All the terms in the recurrence relation are positive, but we're get negative and complex numbers.

The problem is has to do with the `I π + Log[-1 + a]` factor in the exponent.  The other factors turn the solution into an expression containing a complex power of `1 = E^(2 I π)`.

```
FullSimplify[
 E^(((-1 + a^t) (I π + Log[-1 + a]))/(-1 + a)) // ComplexExpand,
 0 < a < 1 && k0 > 0 && t ∈ Integers && t > 0]

(* (1 - a)^((-1 + a^t)/(-1 + a)) E^((2 I (-1 + a^t) π)/(-1 + a)) *)
```

But it should be a real power of the positive base `1 - a`:

```
FullSimplify[
 E^(I \[Pi] + Log[-1 + a]) // ComplexExpand, 
 0 < a < 1 && k0 > 0 && t \[Element] Integers && t > 0]

(* 1 - a *)
```

Almost anything you do to get rid of the extraneous factor seems like cheating, but the answer is erroneous anyway.

**Simpler fix**

My orginal answer was the result of spending time trying and failing to get *Mathematica* to look at `k[t]^a` as a real exponential instead of a complex exponential.  But if we're going to cheat, then a simpler way is to replace the troublesome `I π + Log[-1 + a]` by `Log[1 - a]`, which is what it should be:

```
rsol /. (I \[Pi] + Log[-1 + a]) -> Log[1 - a]

(* {k[t] -> (1 - a)^((-1 + a^t)/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t} *)
```

**Original fix**

Here's a way that gets and simplifies `E^(I \[Pi] + Log[-1 + a])` within the expression using an extra `TransformationFunctions`:

```
Simplify[
 E^(((-1 + a^t) (I π + Log[-1 + a]))/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t,
 0 < a < 1 && k0 > 0 && t \[Element] Integers && t > 0,
 TransformationFunctions -> {
   Automatic,
   # /. Power[E, pow_] :> (
      ComplexExpand[E^#]^(pow/#) &@
        First @ Cases[pow, _?(! FreeQ[#, I] &)]) &}]

(* (1 - a)^((-1 + a^t)/(-1 + a)) k0^a^t *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Well, in the end I'll got to work with my manual solution. More worrying is that _Mathematica's_ answer provides wrong numbers when we provide numeric values for the parameters. I am new to Mathematica, but that indeed seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The recursively defined function works if a numerical value of a (0

Here is a "cheat" using a wrapper then changing the form. It returns a form perhaps closer to the desired result:

```
k[n_, a_] := (1 - w[a]) k[n - 1, w@a]^w[a];
k[0, a_] := k0
```

then

```
FullSimplify[k[4, q] /. w -> ToExpression]
```

yields:

```
-(-1 + q) (-(-1 + q) (-(-1 + q) (-k0^q (-1 + q))^q)^q)^q
```

Continuing the cheat:

```
cheat[u_, var_] := Module[{a1, a2, a3, e1, e2},
  a1 = Simplify[u] /. (-1 + var) -> -h;
  a2 = a1 /. h -> 1;
  a3 = a1 /. k0 -> 1;
  e1 = Times @@ Cases[a2, Power[__, x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}];
  e2 = Times @@ Cases[a3, Power[_, x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}];
  (1 - var)^e2 k0^e1]
```

Tabulating from 1 to 6 (omitted 0 as case is defined and not accounted in cheat):

```
TableForm[
 Table[{j, cheat[k[j, m] /. w -> ToExpression, m]}, {j, 1, 6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks. However, it is a rather a cumbersome way for getting a solution for an easy problem.

Comment: I agree entirely, hence my use of 'cheat' not really apt but am time poor at present...using Assuming and Assumptions did not work for me hence work around...

Comment: When I defined recursively with condition on a I get correct form. Posted only to show symbolic manipulation could be forced. Look forward to insights from other answers. Happy holidays and peace to all.